# Extract numbers from cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a column where cells contain phone numbers in the following format:

```
To: +6112312414 Will Smith To: +61832892357 Tom Hopkins To: +447857747717 Julius Caesar
```

Or

```
From: +44712423110 Jack Russel To: 112312414 Mr XYZ To: +61832892357 Hulk
```

I need to extract the recipient phone numbers in a separate column, names not required e.g.

`+6112312414, +61832892357, +447857747717` for the first example and `112312414, +61832892357` for the second example. Can someone please help with this? Thanks!

Comment: You want the output in one cell with a comma?

Comment: What have you tried - Stack Overflow isn't a programming service. That said this is fairly trivial. Write a vba function to loop over string and use the isnumeric function (with a check for a + symbol) to pull out the phone numbers.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes please

Comment: @Kevin I tried a few formulae using search, find and mid functions, but I'm only able to extract the first phone number..perhaps you are right, the problem can only be solved by the use of loops and not a single formula..

Comment: do you not want the From number in the second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function PhoneList(st As String) As String
    Dim v As String
    PhoneList = ""
    v = Replace(st, "To: ", Chr(1))
    arr = Split(v, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        If InStr(a, Chr(1)) > 0 Then
            PhoneList = PhoneList & ", " & a
        End If
    Next a
    PhoneList = Replace(PhoneList, Chr(1), "")
    PhoneList = Mid(PhoneList, 3, 9999)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: @Kevin  I will review my answer

Comment: @Kevin this works by my test.  It only returns the Recipients like the OP wants.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - it will if he doesn't want the from number. I reread the post, your aswer is good.

Comment: Thank @Gary'sStudent!

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the data from the column using text to column. Apply the other method and select the colon as extraction :. Then you would be left with the a 'space'+number...note the 'space' denotes just one white space. 
Next, use the replace all column to remove the space, and you are left with just the +number.

Comment: Thanks, I could do that...but I want an automated solution rather than a multi-step process..

Comment: V.Asher you could code it in VBA, then run it as a macro to automate it, are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: a bit..I have implemented @Gary'sStudent! 's VBA answer which works perfectly..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select a blank cell that is adjacent to the list you want to extract number only, and type this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A2,ROW($1:$25),1))* ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10)`

(A2 stands the first data you want to extract numbers only from the list), then press Shift + Ctrl + Enter buttons, and drag the fill handle to fill the range you need to apply this formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use TEXTJOIN as an array

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))="To:",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)))*99+1,99)),""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works in O365, unfortunately I need it to work with older versions of Excel as well..but thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 0):

First you should convert the cell to columns, after that you should go to a blank cell and write this command    =B1 & " " & "," & " " & F1 & " " & "," & " " & J1

this command is for your first example because the reference cells in the command contain the numbers 
if you want to apply the same command just modify the reference cell as you want
[image]